# Updating the value of DynamoDB table with boto3 implemented lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to achieve an update operation using my API method to update the content of the table.

I have following lambda code set up:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    param = event['queryStringParameters']['employeID']
     name = event['queryStringParameters']['employeName']
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-1")
    table = dynamodb.Table('api_demo_employe')
    
    response = table.update_item(
        Key = {
            'employeID' : param
        }
        
        )
```

I need to figure out how can i set the **UpdateExpression,ConditionExpression,     ExpressionAttributeValues** using my update variable.

Could any one help me out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
response = table.update_item(TableName=table, 
                             ReturnValues='UPDATED_NEW',
                             Key={'employeID': {'S': param}},
                             ExpressionAttributeValues={':f': {'S': update['some_param']},
                                                     ':limit': {'N': '500'}},
                             UpdateExpression='SET some_field = :f',
                             ConditionExpression='some_other_field > :limit'
                            )
```

Of course this is just an example--your specific expressions will depend on what you are trying to do.  And I am guessing at your data types.  The `'S'` is for a string, but there are other options for other data types.  You define the substitution variables in `ExpressionAttributeValues` and then reference those in the `UpdateExpression` and `ConditionExpression` as needed.

Full details of all the options are available at https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_item  You'll want to review those options and look at the good examples there for how to do different things.

Comment: i have updated the question after trying out the solution

Comment: The syntax you used is incorrect.  Look at the example I posted in my answer for how the :f attribute is defined: `':f': {'S': update['some_param']}`  You need to define yours similarly: `':f': {'S': name}`  Each attribute must have the data type declared, which is what the S portion defines.  It says essentially that this is to be treated as a String.

Comment: Same goes for your key--you need to specify the type in that as well: `Key={'employeID': {'S': param}}`

Comment: I had missed a : with that the reason i was getting that error. 
Once i wrote ':f' : name it worked :) Thank you so much

Comment: could you help me out with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283009/updateexpression-taking-dynamic-values-for-update-function-in-dynamodb-table-usi

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out with help of @Shawn answer

```
 response = table.update_item(
    Key = {
        'employeID' : param
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {
    
        ':f': name
    },
    UpdateExpression = 'SET employeName = :f'
    
    )
```

And it worked.